# Mysql DISTINCT still return duplicate value

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, distinct, group-concat

How can i avoid getting duplicate on `friends` i still get two `bob` instead only one `bob`

My table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO users (id, name)
VALUES (1, "Gregor"),
    (2, "Liza"),
    (3, "Matt"),
    (4, "Tim"),
    (5, "Lance"),
    (6, "Bob");
    
CREATE TABLE committee(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT,
    friend_id INT,
    member_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`friend_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO committee (user_id, friend_id, member_id)
VALUES (3, 5, 1),
(4, 5, 1),
(3, 6, 2),
(3, 6, 2),
(4, 6, 2);
```

query i use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(f.name) AS friends
FROM committee c
INNER JOIN users u ON (u.id = c.user_id)
INNER JOIN committee c2 ON c2.user_id = c.user_id
INNER JOIN users AS f ON (f.id = c2.friend_id)
WHERE (c.member_id = 1)
GROUP BY u.id;
```

current result:

```
name    friends
Matt    Lance,Bob,Bob
Tim Lance,Bob
```

what i expect:

```
name    friends
Matt    Lance,Bob
Tim Lance,Bob
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `DISTINCT` inside `GROUP_CONCAT()` only:

```
SELECT u.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.name) AS friends
................................................
```

Note that `SELECT DISTINCT ...` does not make sense in your query because you are using `GROUP BY` which returns distinct rows for each user.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fea24cfbb677e001948c703f7d7483fd).

Comment: I still get Bob twice

Comment: @Printer see the demo in my edited answer. There are no duplicates.

Comment: Weird, it works on your demo and not mine ^^

Question if i would like to replace `GROUP_CONCAT` with `JSON_ARRAYAGG(DISTINCT JSON_OBJECT('name', f.name))`

But it does not work

Comment: @Printer from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg DISTINCT is not allowed in JSON_ARRAYAGG

Comment: Ah any tips what i could do instead?

Comment: @Printer Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e4c84003d54651df2e703b85ae80f1f7

Comment: @Printer I suspect that you are using www.sqlfiddle.com to run your queries. I don't know why but it returns duplicates: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e3b7b8/5 This must be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You have distinct u.name not in f.name

Try this

```
SELECT u.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct f.name) AS friends
FROM committee c
INNER JOIN users u ON (u.id = c.user_id)
INNER JOIN committee c2 ON c2.user_id = c.user_id
INNER JOIN users AS f ON (f.id = c2.friend_id)
WHERE (c.member_id = 1)
GROUP BY u.name;
```

Comment: I still get Bob twice

Comment: Try this have edited my answer